# how to get primary key value of newly inserted user in zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

i have a problem on my project im currently working on and
this is my register controller
every time a user registers there will be a default image that will be displayed in their profile

```
      public function registerAction()
       {
      $form = new Application_Form_Users();
    $form->submit->setLabel('Register');
    $this->view->form = $form ;

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

    $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
            $id = $form->getValue('uid');
            $firstname = $form->getValue('firstname');
            $lastname  = $form->getValue('lastname');
            $email     = $form->getValue('email');
            $username  = $form->getValue('username');
            $password  = $form->getValue('password');
            $vpassword = $form->getValue('vpassword');

            if ($password == $vpassword) { 
            $register = new Application_Model_DbTable_Users();
            $password = md5($password);
            $register->addUser($firstname , $lastname , $email , $username , $password );


            if ($register) {
                        $register = new Application_Model_DbTable_Users();
                        $uid = $form->populate($register->getUser($id));

                        $addimg = new Application_Model_DbTable_Images();
                        $imagepath = APPLICATION_PATH.'/../public/upload/';
                        $addimg->addImage($uid , $imagepath);
                    }
            $this->_helper->redirector('index');
            } else { 
            $this->view->errorMessage = "Passwords don't match.";
            }
            } else {
            $form->populate($formData);
            }
        }

}
```

this is my function to add default image path into my database

```
            public function addImage($uid , $imgpath)
    {
        $data = array(
        'uid'      => $uid ,
        'imgpath'  => $imgpath ,
        );
        $this->insert($data);
    }
```

but i got an error because my uid is null my question is how to get the value of uid in my users table,  also users table and images table have a relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Zend_Db_Table` then you can do something like this in `addUser()`:

```
public function addUser($firstname , $lastname , $email , $username , $password ){
    $user = $this->createRow();
    $user->fname = $firstname;
    $user->lname = $lastname;
    ...
    $user->save();
    return $user->id;
}
```

This will return you user id so you can do:

```
$id = $register->addUser($firstname , $lastname , $email , $username , $password );
```

and

```
$addimg->addImage($id , $imagepath); //$id, not $uid !
```

Comment: thanks for your answers to solve my problem i just change my logic ,but i might use this in my upcoming projects thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put a default value for $imgpath in your database for each new entry.

Comment: my problem sir is uid it has no value so the addImage($uid,$imgpath); is having an error

Comment: yeah i understood, i gave you an other way to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lastInsertId()` function within the `Zend_Db_Adapter` class.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.write.lastinsertid

In your case it should be:

```
$this->getAdapter()->lastInsertId()
```

after your last line in the `addImage` method.

**Warning:** This does not work with all SQL adapters (like PostgreSQL)

Comment: how can i use that sir do you have a sample? im just a newbie thankyou

Comment: my adapter is pdo_mysql please tell how to use that lastInsertId function

Answer (score 0):

From what i can get from your code, you're adding a new user, and then, adding an image related to his id.

```
 $uid = $form->populate($register->getUser($id));
 $addimg = new Application_Model_DbTable_Images();
 $imagepath = APPLICATION_PATH.'/../public/upload/';
 $addimg->addImage($uid , $imagepath);
```

And, you get an "error" because $uid is null. But $id shouldn't be null, and it should be the ID of the user you just added.

So you might try this and see if it works for you

```
$addimg->addImage($id , $imagepath);
```